# ¿Como enviar una List<T> de un webform a otro?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, asp, webforms

Tengo un datalist que lleno de informacion de la siguiente manera:

```
   //Crear lista de la clase productos
   List<Producto> producto = new List<Producto>();

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateBinding();
    }
    public void UpdateBinding()
    {

        DataProducto.DataSource = producto;
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Nombre_prod";
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Descrip_prod";
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Precio_Unit";
        DataProducto.DataMember = "Img_origen";
        DataProducto.DataMember = "ID_producto";
        DataProducto.DataBind();

    }
```

creo una lista de productos e inserto los items dentro de un Datalist que se llama `Dataproducto`. Un botón de busqueda selecciona la información de la base de datos que el usuario busca:

```
    protected void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess bd = new DataAccess();
        producto = bd.GetProducto(txtbusqueda.Text);
        UpdateBinding();
    }
```

el asunto es que, el datalist tiene un botón de agregar al carrito:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_agregar" runat="server" Text="Agregar" OnClick="Btn_agregar_Click" />
```

Este botón se repetirá por cada producto encontrado en mi base de datos e intenté ponerle `CommandName="addtocart"` y `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID_producto") %>'`

pero cuando al datalist le doy la acción

```
protected void DataProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "addtocart")
        {
            Response.Redirect("cart.aspx?id=" + 
            e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        }
    }
```

me manda error: "Eventargs no contiene definicion para CommandName".

Comment: Estuve viendo mi problema y parece que era mas simple de lo que parece. Mi datalist tenía el evento `DataProducto_SelectedIndexChanged` y era necesario cambiarlo por el evento `DataProducto_ItemCommand`, el problema es que ahora mi botón no realiza accion alguna. Mas información después

Answer (score 1):

Si analizamos la dcumentacion del evento

[BaseDataList.SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8)

y la del argumento `EventArgs`

[EventArgs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventargs?view=netframework-4.8#fields)

en ningun lado se observa que exista un propiedad `CommandName` quizas te estas confundiendo de control con los eventos del `GridView`

[GridView.RowCommand Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand?view=netframework-4.8)

en donde si existe el command como parte del argumento de evento

ahora bien, algo que observo es que no asignas los datos de la lista a un objeto `Session` para poder usarlo entre los diferente eventos

Estas invocando el `UpdateBinding()` desde el `Load` cuando quien carga los datos es el `Click` de `btnBuscar`, eso es incorrecto